# ICEPush break's Vaadin 7 application

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, vaadin, icepush

I have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

in my pom.xml.

Application starting with servlet

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = true, ui = TAISUI.class)
public class ApplicationServlet extends ICEPushServlet implements SessionInitListener {
```

Application build and deploy completes successfully but when I try to open my app in browser tab I get

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/icepush/servlet/MainServlet;

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.50, Vaadin 7.1.12. Instead of web.xml I'm using own WebApplicationInitializer implementation with Spring context registration:

```
public class TaisWebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(TaisConfiguration.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
    }
}
```

Why do I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/icepush/servlet/MainServlet;?

Comment: Fixed by adding org.icepush.icepush dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: You might also look at the built-in Server Push feature.

Comment: @wypieprz, yes, I'm using it now, thanks.